# Pass multiple variables through link (reads only one)

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass some variables from a link but for some reason it only reads one of them. Below is the link and the code. `roundNo` shows up fine.

`archery/viewround.php?gameNo=1&roundNo=7`

```
    echo $_GET['gameNo'];
    echo $_GET['roundNo'];
  echo "<table border><tr><th>Round ID</th><th>Match Name</th><th>Player Name</th><th>Shot 1</th><th>Shot 2</th><th>Shot 3</th><th>Shot 4</th><th>Shot 5</th><th>Shot 6</th><th>Shot 7</th><th>Shot 8</th><th>Shot 9</th><th>Shot 10</th></tr>";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $tempPlayerName = getnamewithid($row["player_id"]);
    $tempMatchName = getmatchnamewithid($_GET['gameNo']);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row["round_id"].'</td>';
    echo "<td>" . $tempMatchName. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $tempPlayerName. "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row["shot_1"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["shot_2"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["shot_3"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["shot_4"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["shot_5"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["shot_6"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["shot_7"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["shot_8"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["shot_9"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["shot_10"] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Did you check print_r($_REQUEST)

Comment: Shows up fine for me. What statements do you have before the echo?

Comment: DB connection but still i put on top of the file but still doesn't show up. [link](http://i39.tinypic.com/2ikzlhd.png)

Comment: Did try `print_r($_REQUEST)` shows up `Array ( [roundNo] => 10` after that it starts with PHPSSID etc etc

Comment: Weird...try `archery/viewround.php?&gameNo=1&roundNo=7` and `archery/viewround.php?roundNo=7&gameNo=1` and let us know what you see.

Comment: Nope, had already tried the second option before.Even if i try with a new variable it still won't get it

Comment: Try `archery/viewround.php?&gameNo=1&roundNo=7&testNo=123` and `echo $_GET['testNo'];`  <-- To eliminate the chance that you can read only 1 GET variable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44764/discussion-between-user007-and-teris-l)